# '..nach A oder nach B oder beides' oder '..oder beidem' oder '..oder nach beidem'

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case

Welche der Versionen ist grammatisch am besten, oder zumindest am wenigsten falsch? Ich tendiere zu 1 oder 3, kann hier aber keine Fachbegriffe zuordnen, so dass ich mich nicht selbst auf einschlägigen Seiten kundig machen konnte.

Antworten bitte mit Votum und Benennung der Regel

1. Der Händler kann aussuchen ob die Eintragung nach Datum oder nach Kilometerstand (oder beides) erfolgen soll.
2. Der Händler kann aussuchen ob die Eintragung nach Datum oder nach Kilometerstand (oder beidem) erfolgen soll.
3. Der Händler kann aussuchen ob die Eintragung nach Datum oder nach Kilometerstand (oder nach beidem) erfolgen soll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Präposition "nach" erfordert den Dativ: "... ob die Eintragung nach **dem** Datum oder nach **dem** Kilometerstand ..."
Regel: zum Beispiel [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Dativ.html).

Somit ist die Version 1 nicht richtig.

Bei Version 2 oder 3 ist es eher eine Frage des Stils, wie oft man das Wort "nach" wiederholen möchte, richtig sind beide Versionen. Hier wäre denkbar eine weitere Version zu nehmen:

> Der Händler kann aussuchen, ob die Eintragung nach Datum oder Kilometerstand (oder beidem) erfolgen soll.

Das heißt "nach" wird nur einmal verwendet. Version 3 verwendet "nach" dann immer und Version 2 wäre ein Mittelding.

Für welche dieser drei Versionen man sich entscheidet, ist meines Erachtens Geschmackssache. Ein "richtig" oder "falsch" gibt es hier nicht.

Comment: Was haltet ihr von dieser Variante? "Der Händler kann aussuchen, ob die Eintragung nach Datum, Kilometerstand oder beidem erfolgen soll."

Comment: @Chupa Das entspricht [Toms Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49966/19201)

Answer (score 6):

Keine!

Mein Vorschlag:

- *Der Händler kann aussuchen, ob die Eintragung nach Datum,
  Kilometerstand oder beidem erfolgen soll.*

---

Die Kommaregel lautet, dass Nebensätze mit Komma abgetrennt werden sollen. Die Frage *nach wem* erfordert den Dativ. Der Rest ist bloß Stil.

Comment: Danke! Ist das Komma nach 'aussuchen' Pflicht? In einem Nebensatz hätte ich auch 'beidem' gewählt, dachte aber die Klammer ändert die Sachlage.

Comment: Ja, dieses Komma ist soweit ich weiß Pflicht. Trennung von Hauptsatz und Nebensatz.

Answer (score 1):

Neben IQVs Antwort:

- Der Händler kann aussuchen, ob die Eintragung nach Datum, Kilometerstand oder beidem erfolgen soll.

kann man auch schreiben:

- Der Händler kann aussuchen ob die Eintragung nach Datum oder nach Kilometerstand oder ob beides erfolgen soll.